# browser not getting my python server cookie?

Tags: python, cookies

My challenge is sending my cookie along with my payload.  I'm simply adding a cookie to an existing, and running program.  The payload (song) is getting there just fine. And, I'm not getting any errors at the browser console.

I seem to be able to send a cooke, along with my JSON data just fine.

When I look at the headers in Chrome's Developer's Tools, I see the cookie.  But, when I look for the cookie in the Application>>Cookie tab, nothing is there.  So, a cookie header seems to be sent, by the client is not storing it.

And, at the client.... document.cookie is null.

My test code is creating a single cookie called sessionID.

Here is the Response Header in Chrome:  You can see my fake sessionID cookie:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true 

 Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null

 Content-Type:text/plain

 Date:Wed, 23 Nov 2016 22:41:10 GMT

 Server:BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.2

 Set-Cookie:sessionID=4jjdd7ghhq
```

Here is the screenshot indicating No Cookies.
[no cookies in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Udh.png)

Here is my server code, written in Python3:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.send_response(200)       
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", self.headers["Origin"])
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")            
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    self.end_headers()
    return

def do_GET(self):
    if self.path.startswith("/songs/ID"):
        self.load_cookie()
        db=MediaDB()
        ID = self.parseID(self.path)
        song = db.getSong(ID)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', self.headers["Origin"])
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true") 
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")      
        self.cookie["sessionID"] = "4jjdd7ghhq"
        self.send_cookie()
        self.end_headers()
        json_string = json.dumps(song)
        self.wfile.write(bytes(json_string, "utf-8"))
    elif self.path.startswith("/songs"):
        self.getSongs()
        return
    else:
        self.badPath()
        return  


def load_cookie(self):
    if "Cookie" in self.headers:
        self.cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie(self.headers["Cookie"])
    else:
        self.cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
    return

def send_cookie(self):
    for morsel in self.cookie.values():
        self.send_header("Set-Cookie", morsel.OutputString())
    return

================
```

My searches have come up short.  If there is something out there that might help me, I appreciate you pointing that out.  Oh, by the way, my skin's pretty thick, so if I'm doing something stupid - it's okay to point it out... I gotta learn somehow. ha!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support cookies when working with local files by default, as I see is your case by the screenshot you posted.

However, you can change this by starting Chrome with the `--enable-file-cookies` flag.

See more about it [in this post](http://wolfslittlestore.be/2012/08/cookies-on-local-files-in-chrome/).

Comment: My Chrome is able to support local cookies, I have a cookie test that works just fine without adding the payload of the JSON.  However, I used the above -enable-file-cookies, but still not working for me.  Thanks.